# Python: Get Twitter Trends in tweepy, and parse JSON

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

*Ok, so please note this is my first post*

So, I am trying to use Python to get Twitter Trends, I am using python 2.7 and Tweepy.

I would like something like this (which works):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tweepy
consumer_key = 'secret'
consumer_secret = 'secret'
access_token = 'secret'
access_token_secret = 'secret'
# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
trends1 = api.trends_place(1)

print trends1
```

That gives a massive JSON string,

I would like to extract each trend name to a variable, in string format `str(trendsname)` ideally.

Which would ideally have the names of trends like so:
    `trendsname = str(trend1) + " " +str(trend2) + " "`
and so on, for each of the trend names.

Please note I am only learning Python.

Comment: Are you aware of the built-in `json` module and its `json.loads()` function?

Comment: @senshin Yes, I was aware of it, but am unsure of how to use it.

Comment: Okay, in that case, post the contents of `trends1`. If it's too large to fit here, stick it in a [pastie](http://pastie.org).

Comment: @senshin Ok: http://pastie.org/8644855 I believe I want to extract the "`u'name': u'#PolandNeedsWWATour',`" value, for instance, just have the "`#PolandNeedsWWATour`" on its own, and do that for every name of trend, if that makes sense

Comment: Please note that Tweepy version 4.0 has renamed the `trends_place` method to `get_place_trends`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Tweepy deserializes the JSON for you. As such, `trends1` is just an ordinary Python list. This being the case, you can simply do the following:

```
trends1 = api.trends_place(1) # from the end of your code
# trends1 is a list with only one element in it, which is a 
# dict which we'll put in data.
data = trends1[0] 
# grab the trends
trends = data['trends']
# grab the name from each trend
names = [trend['name'] for trend in trends]
# put all the names together with a ' ' separating them
trendsName = ' '.join(names)
print(trendsName)
```

Result:

```
#PolandNeedsWWATour #DownloadElyarFox #DünMürteciBugünHaşhaşi #GalatasaraylılıkNedir #KnowTheTruth Tameni Video Anisa Rahma Mikaeel Manado JDT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would vote up, but it says I need 15 reputation. **ignore the following statement, it works!** Can I set trends1 to the source of the JSON string? I will assume so.

Comment: @RPiPasswordGen You should set `trends1 = api.trends_place(1)` like you have in your question. Is that what you're asking? (I edited that into my answer just now)

Answer (score 6):

I think the following code works fine too:

```
trends1 = api.trends_place(1)
trends = set([trend['name'] for trend in trends1[0]['trends']])
print trends
```